# mplayer seek times seem fixed. Can they be customized?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, mplayer

Does `mplayer` actually allow custom seek times?  ie. change the default 10s to 4s.
I'm running `mplayer` natively in the terminal. ie. not via a gui wrapper such as *smplayer*.
Nothing changes when I follow the suggested method.

My conf file is `~/.mplayer/input.conf` — It contains only the following 2 lines:

```
RIGHT seek +4
LEFT seek -4
```

I understand that seeking can be influenced by the location of key-frames (especially in video)...  However I want this for **audio only**.

Because it didn't work with a *`.mp3`*, I tried it with an *uncompressed `.wav`* ... Still nothing changed.. My left and right keys still moved 10 seconds.

This is the command I used:

```
mplayer -input conf=~/.mplayer/input.conf  audio.wav
```

I tried larger values *(seek 140)* but it still didn't work..
Is this feature broken, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using mplayer in Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the probleme is that mplayer don't undertand the ~ in `~/.mplayer/input.conf`. run it as

```
mplayer -input conf=$HOME/.mplayer/input.conf  audio.wav
```

or better yet

```
mplayer audio.wav
```

as mplayer should look for the content of $HOME/.mplayer/input.conf without you asking for it.

Comment: *@Rémi:*  I was aware that the option wasn't explicitly needed, but I hadn't realized that the `=` prevents the expansion... However, that doesn't explain the problem, because `mplayer` falls back to looking for `input.conf` in that directory... !!!??? What??? .. ok, the path was wrong (it didn't report an error.. ok-ish).. but then **why** shouldn't/wouldn't it work? .. the file was **actually there**... You have certainly highlighted the root of the problem... It clicked!... `input.conf` had a trailing space in its name... It works like a charm now with `mplayer audio.mp3` :) ..*Thanks!*

Comment: PS. `mplayer -input audio.wav` doesn't work.. `input` must by followed by a command. The commands can be listed via: `mplayer -input cmdlist`

Comment: yep, forgot to remove it when copying and pasting command, it done now

Comment: I think my space came from a copy-paste too ;)